# Which .NET DataType for SQL-Query-Data as webservice return?

Tags: c#, web-services, types

I am coding a webservice in ASPX which queries a local SQL-Database:

```
SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
```

my question which complex DataType (obviously serializable) should I use? One which my WinFroms-Client can receive and put in a DataGridView for presentation?

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridView` can bind to **any** objects, so I recommend returning Plain Old CLR Objects (POCO).

Don't return `DataSets` or `DataTable`s, because those will cause a large amount of XML to be transferred over the wire, which isn't needed.  Also, that makes your webservice all-but-unusable for alternative clients like Java.  That might not be one of your requirements at the moment, but you're writing a **web** service, not a .NET remoting service.  Therefore you should write an API that is in the spirit of the web, using simple, discoverable XML.

The scenario you're describing here is that the **Data Transfer Object** enterprise design pattern.  Take a look at the following references:

- [Data transfer objects on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)
- [Data transfer objects by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Comment: you have an interesting point there, ill have to look into that. thx

Answer (score -3):

DataTable or DataSet

Comment: For speedy development these work great. For performance and maintainability they suck.